# onSeekBarChangeListener causes null object exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I add a new folder called raw with a mp3 file in it in res folder.Below I added a full program , After adding setOnSeekBarChangeListener shows null point error the ide does show any error but the app keeps crashing.I tried to search but nothing helps.It takes several of my hours but not no luck.
Device Name Nexus API 24  Os ver 7.0 thnx

```
package com.example.m1.audiodemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    public void playAudio(View view) {

        mediaplayer.start();
    }

    public void pauseAudio(View view) {
        mediaplayer.pause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.somempthree);



        SeekBar volumeControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        volumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {


          Log.i("progress bar", Integer.toString(progress));
        }

    });



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this code after setContentView

```
    SeekBar volumeControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    volumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {


      Log.i("progress bar", Integer.toString(progress));
    }

});
```

Comment: Thnx for the hint the line I added is setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); I think this help other who is new to android

Comment: Welcome. If it helps you then you can accept it write answer.